# dvi to eps conversion

Tags: dvi, postscript

It's possible to convert `dvi` to `eps` format each page like http://www.tug.org/texinfohtml/dvipng.html. I want each page `equation` convert to `eps` format.

Comment: dvips p *pagenumber* -E -o foo.eps foo.dvi  ... a quick idea, untested

Comment: I have found `dvips -E -i* -o f00.eps foo.dvi`. But the `.eps` extension is not generated.

Comment: Try `dvips -E* -o foo.eps foo.dvi`. It worked for me once.

Comment: * is a suffix, 0 to turn off. So use -E, -E0, -i, -i0, etc.